# JavaScript Dropdown menu in WordPress dissapears when I try to mouse over it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Can't find a sollution anywhere, the dropdown menu keep on disappearing when I point the parent menu and try to move on to the drop-down. The website is [www.skillraise.net](http://www.skillraise.net).

Comment: you have a css problem, not js

Comment: Okay,nice start,can you give me some tips how to fix that because it seems i cant do it on my own ;[

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your /wp-content/themes/Underfire/style.css file:

```
.sub-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    left: -5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could accept my answer as answer to your question. It would be nice of you. Thanks in advance.